# Problem with Flutter framework, old code doesn't work

Tags: android, animation, dart, widget, flutter

A week ago I was looking for an animated collapse cardview in flutter
and i found this code from another user:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49034627/10748167

It worked and it was all very good, but yesterday when I reopened the  project I saw that now the animated container doesn't hide the text inside but shows only the animation.

Another problem is also that the card is flat and doesn't have the material border. I don't know how to solve this problem considering that the code worked a week ago. Any Advice?

@aziza  is the owner of the code from the link that I shared

now it's look like this : https://ibb.co/5vzSzms

Reported as bug in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25028

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean`? Please add the code to your question that doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: i added the code in the question , it worked one week ago but know the text doesn't hide more and the card doesn't have the border , i also have tried to reinstall android studio with fluttere framework but also doens't work.

Comment: Remove the color of the Container in the GestureDetector.

Comment: the ocolor is of the container , and how i sad before this code worked for me a week ago , but maybe with some update or other thinks it doesn't work more

Comment: Wrap `AnimatedContainer` with a `ClipRect`.

Comment: @Simon , ok now it works , but there is aniway the problem of the card shape , it's rectangular...

Comment: @Simon and why is it neccesary to wrap it in another widget? Like i said that code worked for me a weeks ago

Comment: Use `ClipRRect` then

Comment: @Simon , where i need to use it? can you post how the code will be look like

Comment: @Simon I want also to understand why now I need to use ClipRRect widget , is it an update of flutter? I'm really confused