# Flutter Collapsible / Expansible card

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to match this design

[image]

on tap the card should expand

[image]

I cannot use a card wrapping an expansion tile because the expansion tile is basically only one row, I was trying to follow this example 
[flutter_catalog](https://github.com/X-Wei/flutter_catalog/blob/master/lib/routes/home.dart)

I googled a lot and could not find an example of what I am trying to achieve, the closest thing I could find on stackoverflow was this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029841/how-to-animate-collapse-elements-in-flutter) is there not in flutter a collapsible / expansible card?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can absolutely use a `Card` wrapping an `ExpansionTile`. The `ExpansionTile` has a `title` property which takes a `Widget` so you can pass any `Widget` you want into it.

Messy example code, but hopefully you get the idea:

```
class ExpandedTile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
      elevation: 2,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: _buildTitle(),
          trailing: SizedBox(),
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Herzlich Willkommen"),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.check),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Das Kursmenu"),
                  Spacer(),
                  Icon(Icons.check),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTitle() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("MODUL 1"),
            Spacer(),
            Text("Mehr"),
          ],
        ),
        Text("Kursubersicht"),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("6 Aufgaben"),
            Spacer(),
            FlatButton.icon(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 8.0),
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
              label: Text("Fortsetzen"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

produces

[image: Screenshot]

and when tapped

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are clearly a flutter expert, thanks for your answer